# $\theta$ is real if and only if $e^{i\theta}$ is in circle

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Let us define $e^z = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!},$ where $z$ is a complex number. I want to show that, $\theta$ is real if and only if $e^{i\theta}$ is in circle.
That is, I want to show $\theta \in \mathbb R$ iff $\left| e^{i\theta}\right| =1.$
First of all I know that, if $\theta$ is real then we have
$$\left| e^{i\theta}\right|=\sin^2\theta +\cos^2 \theta =1.$$
But I am unable to prove the other direction, that is, if $\left| e^{i\theta}\right|=1$ then how can I show that $\theta \in \mathbb R?$
Thank you for your time and help. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: suppose $\theta=a+ib$ was not real. Then...

Comment: @CalvinKhor Then $|e^{i\theta}|=e^{-b}$ and this will be $1$ only if $b=0$, hence $\theta =a $ is real. Am I correct?

Comment: yes. A minor point: you don't need to use a contradiction. (not B) implies (not A) is the same as proving A implies B (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you.